# How do I force the VS designer to not generate code for already existing datagridview columns?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I've got a subclass of DataGridView that adds all the columns it needs in it's own constructor, but when I use this component in the VS designer it insists on generating code to add the same columns on top of the ones added in the component constructor. How do I force it to not generate code for columns it already finds populated inside a datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off autogeneration of columns before binding your datasource:

```
datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
datagridview.DataSource = mydatasource;
```

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you said the designer was creating the columns.  My answer would be applicable only at binding time.